# Tkinter window throwing error when trying to tk.root.state('zoomed')

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey everyone this is my first run using `Tkinter` library in Python and I am trying to have my app, once launched to be in a full screen state.

My code is as follows:

`self.controller.state("zoomed")`

code:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='#47476b')
    self.controller = controller     
    self.controller.title('J-K BitCoin ATM')
    self.controller.state("normal")
    self.controller.iconphoto(True,tk.PhotoImage(file='bitcoin-bag.png'))
```

This is working on other projects but not the one I am currently building, when I try to run this state I get the error:

```
>return self.tk.call('wm', 'state', self._w, newstate)
_tkinter.TclError: bad argument "zoomed": must be normal, iconic, or withdrawn
```

Is there a package I am missing or how do people get this function in Tkinter to run properly?

Comment: Just one line of code isn't enough to have an idea. Provide more but relevant code.

Comment: ```def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='#47476b')
        self.controller = controller
        self.controller.title('J-K BitCoin ATM')
        self.controller.state("normal")
        self.controller.iconphoto(False,tk.PhotoImage(file='bitcoin-bag.png'))heading_Lable=tk.Label(self,
                                text='BitCoin ATM',
                                font=('PO52',45,'bold'),
                                foreground='white',
                                background='#47476b')
        heading_Lable.pack(pady=25)```

Comment: my syntax got messed up when editing it to fit in the comments but I hope that that will be enough code to help answer my question...

Comment: @SethS.py pls make an edit to your question and place your code there not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

`zoomed` is only valid on windows and OSX. It's not supported on X11-based systems.

From the [official tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M62) upon which tkinter is built:

> wm state window ?newstate? - If newstate is specified, the window will be set to the new state, otherwise it returns the current state of window: either normal, iconic, withdrawn, icon, or (Windows and Mac OS X only) zoomed. The difference between iconic and icon is that iconic refers to a window that has been iconified (e.g., with the wm iconify command) while icon refers to a window whose only purpose is to serve as the icon for some other window (via the wm iconwindow command). The icon state cannot be set.

Comment: thanks for thank, I'm gonna look into i ta little more. I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. But Intel hardware, so you may be right

Comment: I can post the output of lspci is thats any helpful?

Comment: @SethS.py: I apologize, I got my answer completely backwards. "zoomed" only works on Windows and OSX. I'm sorry for the confusion.